# What are the logs that MS Dynamics AX writes in the residing machine that can consume space and memory of the machine?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, business-connector

I have a third party application that is developed in ASP .NET Web Forms and it uses the AX 2009 business connector for the integration of MS Dynamics AX 2009. The machine where the AX 2009 was installed were reducing the performance due to the suspected logs that AX have created. Unfortunately the third party application also is affected because of the AX 2009 were having problems in terms of performance issues. Does the log file overloads the server or the machine itself because of AX?

Thank you very much for any kind answers.

Comment: What file extension do the files have?

Comment: If you find an answer useful then please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about log files but ensure your windows event log is not full, this causes terrible business connector performance issues and is simple to fix, just increase the limit or set to overwrite when full.